# SQL Server: Get the most recent Instance of date record that's added within 90 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have this code where it gets me these columns/data and the tables they belong to:

```
StudentName -- ST 
stunum -- ST    
ssn -- ST 
Campus -- CA    
SchoolStatus -- SS  
Program -- AE
AYStart -- FS
AYEnd -- FS 
AYStatus -- PS  
StaffName -- SF 
fastudentayid -- AU 
DateAdded -- AU
```

This is my code

```
select rtrim(st.lastname) +', '+rtrim(st.FirstName) as StudentName, 
    st.StuNum, 
    st.SSN as SSN, 
    ca.Descrip as Campus, 
    ss.Descrip as SchoolStatus,
    ae.adProgramDescrip as Program, 
    convert(varchar(10),fs.StartDate,101) as AYStart, 
    convert(varchar(10),fs.EndDate,101) as AYEnd, 
    ps.Descrip as AYStatus,
    rtrim(sf.lastname) +', '+rtrim(sf.FirstName) as StaffName,
    fs.faStudentAyID as faStudentAyID,
    convert(varchar(10), MAX(af.DateAdded),101) as DateAdded
from stuTbl (nolock) as ST
join CpsTbl (nolock) as CA
    on ca.CpsID = st.CpsID
join scStatTbl (nolock) as SS
    on ss.ScStatTblID = st.ScStatTblID
join AdEnTbl (nolock) as AE
    on ae.stuTblID = st.stuTblID
join faStAy (nolock) as FS
    on fs.AdEnTblID = ae.AdEnTblID
join FaPStat (nolock) as PS
    on ps.FaPStatID = fs.FaPStatID
join (select RecordID, ColumnName, NewVal, UserID, DateAdded, MAX(DateAdded) as MDA
    from syA_FaPStatTbl
    where ColumnName = 'Package Status'
    and (NewVal = '38' 
    or NewVal = '40'
    or NewVal = '43'
    or NewVal = '67'
    or NewVal = '68')
    and DateAdded between getDate()-90 and getDate()
    group by RecordID, ColumnName, NewVal, UserID, DateAdded) as AF
    on af.RecordID = fs.faStAyID
join StaffTbl (nolock) as SF
    on af.UserID = sf.StaffTblID
where (ps.Descrip = 'Submitted' 
    or ps.Descrip = 'Resubmitted'
    or ps.Descrip = 'Pell Submitted'
    or ps.Descrip = 'Aid Submitted'
    or ps.Descrip = 'Aid Resubmitted')
and af.DateAdded between getDate()-90 and getDate()
Group by st.lastname, st.FirstName, 
    st.StuNum, 
    st.SSN,
    ca.Descrip,
    ss.Descrip, 
    ae.adProgramDescrip,
    fs.StartDate,
    fs.EndDate,
    ps.Descrip,
    sf.lastname, sf.FirstName, 
    fs.faStudentAyID
```

I am getting what I need as far as the data goes in that I am not duplicating entries. My problem is if someone alters the status at the client end software, it pulls both instances where the status was switched to Submitted as long as the change is within 90 days of today's date.

Here's a sample data -- notice Crytal Ball's record? Someone updated the status and submitted it on 5/11 and again on 6/5/2018. I just need the latest record no matter how many times the status is updated regardless of how many times it happened the past 90 days, which in this case is the 6/5/2018 one.

```
Jones, Mary || 124926 || xxx-xx-xxxx || Seattle || Active || MCA Prog || 05/28/2018 || 12/23/2018 || Submitted || Doe, John || 1763799 || 06/06/2018

Doe, Dawn || 126954 || xxx-xx-xxxx || Online || Ready to Start || MBC Prog ||   05/28/2018 || 12/23/2018 || Resubmitted || Jones, Bob, || 1760731 || 06/06/2018

Ball, Crystal || 12399 || xxx-xx-xxxx || Chattanooga || Active || MCA Dipl ||   07/02/2018 || 02/10/2019 || Submitted || Jones, Jenny || 1734032 || 05/11/2018

Ball, Crystal || 12399 || xxx-xx-xxxx || Chattanooga || Active || MCA Dipl || 07/02/2018 || 02/10/2019 || Resubmitted || Tavares, John || 1734032 || 06/05/2018

Barnes, Matt || 11817 || xxx-xx-xxxx || Online || Drop || 4 yr BSAH Mgt ||  04/23/2018 || 11/18/2018 || Submitted || Doe, Luis || 1759782 || 04/27/2018
```

EDIT:
- I've tried putting Top 1 on the JOIN (Select) portion of the code and it doesn't let me pull any records at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use a **[row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)()** to get the right data like below

```
select 
StudentName,StuNum,SSN,Campus,
SchoolStatus,Program,AYStart,AYEnd,AYStatus,
StaffName,faStudentAyID,DateAdded
from
(select *,
    row_number() over( partition by fs.faStudentAyID order by DateAdded) as rn
from
(
    select rtrim(st.lastname) +', '+rtrim(st.FirstName) as StudentName, 
    st.StuNum, 
    st.SSN as SSN, 
    ca.Descrip as Campus, 
    ss.Descrip as SchoolStatus,
    ae.adProgramDescrip as Program, 
    convert(varchar(10),fs.StartDate,101) as AYStart, 
    convert(varchar(10),fs.EndDate,101) as AYEnd, 
    ps.Descrip as AYStatus,
    rtrim(sf.lastname) +', '+rtrim(sf.FirstName) as StaffName,
    fs.faStudentAyID as faStudentAyID,
    convert(varchar(10), MAX(af.DateAdded),101) as DateAdded
from stuTbl (nolock) as ST
join CpsTbl (nolock) as CA
    on ca.CpsID = st.CpsID
join scStatTbl (nolock) as SS
    on ss.ScStatTblID = st.ScStatTblID
join AdEnTbl (nolock) as AE
    on ae.stuTblID = st.stuTblID
join faStAy (nolock) as FS
    on fs.AdEnTblID = ae.AdEnTblID
join FaPStat (nolock) as PS
    on ps.FaPStatID = fs.FaPStatID
join (select RecordID, ColumnName, NewVal, UserID, DateAdded, MAX(DateAdded) as MDA
    from syA_FaPStatTbl
    where ColumnName = 'Package Status'
    and (NewVal = '38' 
    or NewVal = '40'
    or NewVal = '43'
    or NewVal = '67'
    or NewVal = '68')
    and DateAdded between getDate()-90 and getDate()
    group by RecordID, ColumnName, NewVal, UserID, DateAdded) as AF
    on af.RecordID = fs.faStAyID
join StaffTbl (nolock) as SF
    on af.UserID = sf.StaffTblID
where (ps.Descrip = 'Submitted' 
    or ps.Descrip = 'Resubmitted'
    or ps.Descrip = 'Pell Submitted'
    or ps.Descrip = 'Aid Submitted'
    or ps.Descrip = 'Aid Resubmitted')
and af.DateAdded between getDate()-90 and getDate()
Group by st.lastname, st.FirstName, 
    st.StuNum, 
    st.SSN,
    ca.Descrip,
    ss.Descrip, 
    ae.adProgramDescrip,
    fs.StartDate,
    fs.EndDate,
    ps.Descrip,
    sf.lastname, sf.FirstName, 
    fs.faStudentAyID
) t
)t
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you @DhruvJoshi. The way your code was posted didn't exactly work but your advice to add the Row_Number helped and it fixed it.